# How to get the last element inside array using VTL?

Tags: vtl

I am writing AWS AppSync resolver. Where I do need to get the last element in my array. AWS AppSync supports VTL language.

Example:

`#set($items=["color", "taste", "shape"])`

`#set($result="shape")`

I am using $array.size() but didn't work. I don't see any option in  Utility Helpers.
.

`#set($result=$item[$item.size()-1])`

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to make sure you are making the arithmetic operation inside -> set(`$result=$item[$item.size()-1]`);

Set the array size into a separate variable and use another variable to get the last index.

`#set($length=$facts.size())`

`#set($lastIndex = $length - 1)`

`#set($fact=$facts.get($lastIndex))`